# How can I make an exit box by using pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am wondering on how to make an **exit box** in pygame. I created a page with a square and I wanted the page to be closed when the player presses it. I tried to use every method from google and youtube but it didn't work. I think the problem is in the code below as I was using graphics and pygame together.

Code:

```
def runGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background
    while True:
        click = pygame.getMouse()
        x = click.getX()
        y = click.getY()

        if 415 < x < 459 and 20 < y < 65: ##button function to close window
            pygame.close()
```

**This is the whole python program:**

```
from graphics import * 
import pygame
import sys
import random 
from time import sleep

padWidth = 480 #the width the of game 
padHeight = 640 # the length of the game
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
red = (255,0,0)

def writeExit(text):
    global gamePad
    textfont = pygame.font.Font('Ranchers-Regular.ttf', 37) #textfont of the game message 
    text = textfont.render(text, True, red)
    textpos = (428, 20)
    gamePad.blit(text, textpos) #print the text
    pygame.display.update()
    
def drawObject(obj, x, y):
    global gamePad
    gamePad.blit(obj, (int(x), int(y)))

def initGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background
    pygame.init()
    gamePad = pygame.display.set_mode((padWidth, padHeight))
    pygame.display.set_caption('asdhasd') #the title of the game
    background = pygame.image.load('play.png') #import the background image
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

def runGame():
    global gamePad, clock, background
    while True:
        click = pygame.getMouse()
        x = click.getX()
        y = click.getY()

        if 415 < x < 459 and 20 < y < 65: ##button function to close window
            pygame.close()

    onGame = False
    while not onGame:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type in [pygame.QUIT]:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
                
        drawObject(background, 0, 0) #display the background 

        pygame.draw.rect(gamePad, black, (415,20,45,45)) #black rectangle for exit button     
        writeExit('X')
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)
 
    pygame.quit()

initGame()
runGame()
```

The program returns an error: `AttributeError: module 'pygame' has no attribute 'getMouse'`. I wonder if there are other methods to close the page by pressing the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access position of mouse in pygame you need to use `pygame.mouse.get_pos()`. It returns a list with x as the first element and y as the second. Also that mouse-button collision detection does not look right. You can either use a pygame.Surface as your button, instead of `pygame.draw.rect` because pygame surfaces have collision detection functions you can use. Example:

```
mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
surf = pygame.Surface((100, 20)).convert()
surf.fill(color)
window.blit(surf, (position))
if surf.get_rect().collidepoint(mousepos[0], mousepos[1]):
    print("Mouse over the button")
```

If you want to keep `pygame.draw.rect` you can implement a custom collision detection function which might look like this:

```
# mx:mouse x-position, my: mouse-y position, 
# bx:button x-position, by:button y-position, bwidth: button width
# bheight: button height 
def button_mouse(mx, my, bx, by, bwidth, bheight):
    if mx > bx and mx < bx + bwidth: # checking if the mouse is inside the rectange in x axis
        if my > by and my < by + bheight:# checking if the mouse is inside the rectange in y axis 
            return True
    return False
```

Working example:

```
import pygame

window = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 300))

def rectbutton_mouse(mx, my, bx, by, bwidth, bheight):
    if mx > bx and mx < bx + bwidth:
        if my > by and my < by + bheight:
            return True
    return False

def clicked(events, mx, my, bx, by, bwidth, bheight):
    for event in events:
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if rectbutton_mouse(mx, my, bx, by, bwidth, bheight):
                return True
    return False


def button(events, mx, my):
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (0, 0, 0), (200, 100, 200, 60))
    if clicked(events, mx, my, 200, 100, 200, 60):
        print("clicked")

while True:
    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    events = pygame.event.get()
    mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    button(events, mousepos[0], mousepos[1])
    pygame.display.update()
```